# How to get facebook user information like name and profile picture in Azure Mobile Apps Authentication in android?

Tags: android, facebook, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Apps authentication with Facebook in my app. The log in and log out is fine. I can log in with my Facebook but I am having trouble getting additional Facebook details like my profile name and picture. How can I access it with android code?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation on how to get those things?

Comment: I didn't find something in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using client-flow (i.e. the facebook SDK), then just call the facebook graph.

If you are using server-flow, the facebook token is available from the /.auth/me endpoint on your Azure App Service - you can use that for your facebook graph calls.

Comment: How do I access the /.auth/me endpoint ? I can access it in my browser and returns a proper json response. But how do I access it in my android code?

Comment: Just do a regular REST call - it's just a HTTPS request with the X-ZUMO-AUTH header set to your authentication token.